# This PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` query skips the 1rst result that's returned

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I'm transitioning over to PDO prepared statements, and I'm having trouble with the syntax for a basic `SELECT` query with a `WHILE` statement.

The `foreach` statement below echos the correct results, but the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` query is skipping the 1rst result that's returned (so it always echo's one result less than it should).

**PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products"); 
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    echo $row['product_name'].' '.$row['price'].' '.$row['color'], "<br />"; 
}
```

**foreach**

```
foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM products') as $row) {
    echo $row['product_name'].' '.$row['price'].' '.$row['color'], "<br />";  
}
```

Comment: You call fetch before the while.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already fetched the first row before the while loop `$row = $stmt->fetch();`.  If you remove this line, it will work as expected.

Since the while loop will overwrite `$row` on each iteration, it looks like you start with the second row, but what happens is the value of `$row` at the first while loop iteration is overwritten.

To have the loop work the way you have written, you would need to use a [do-while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) construct:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch();
do {
     echo $row['product_name'].' '.$row['price'].' '.$row['color'], "<br />";
} while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Here the value of `$row` will be printed first, before it is overwritten by the `while` condition.

> In this particular case I don't want to echo anything when there aren't any results

If that's the case, then check to see if your query returned any results first. Here I'm being explicit in the check, because if you removed the outer `if`, your `while` loop would still follow your intentions - that is, it won't echo anything if there aren't any results.

However, it is always good to have clear intent in your code:

```
if ($stmt->columnCount()) {
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
       echo $row['product_name'].' '.$row['price'].' '.$row['color'], "<br />"; 
   }
}
```

Comment: OMG! I'm so glad I asked :-D

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a benefit to using a do-while statement, as opposed to removing '$row = $stmt->fetch();'?

Comment: Not really, different strokes for different folks. The only _real_ difference is that a do-while will always run the body (the part between { }) since the "truth check" is done later.

Comment: That's actually really helpful, because in this particular case I don't want to echo anything when there aren't any results :-)

Answer (score 5):

Do not do `$row = $stmt->fetch()` before loop.