# Mysqli array loading drops first entry

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

```
$query_string="SELECT wp_app_tracker.wp_apt_application_date,wp_app_tracker.wp_apt_user FROM wp_app_tracker WHERE wp_app_tracker.wp_apt_user = '" . $current_user_name . "'";

$temp_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_string);
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($temp_result);
$application_row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$row_kounter=0;

while ( $application_row=mysqli_fetch_array($temp_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {......
```

The values in $conn, $current_user_name are valid because I do not get any syntactical error.

I have echo'd $query_string on the webpage and confirmed that the correct number of records are retrieved but while processing in the loop, the while loop does not process the first row in the array.

Can anyone please explain why?

Thank you in advance

Uttam

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470197/this-pdofetch-assoc-query-skips-the-1rst-result-thats-returned and 1000 other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are calling

```
$application_row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

once before the while loop as well.

Comment: Awesome - that was so quick!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2  mysqli_fetch_array calls before entering the loop. This way you will always loose the first row.

Remove the line below and it should work.

```
$application_row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```